# Why .ind empty (with error message from xindy although makeindex is used) when index command is inside an align environment?

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, xindy, makeindex, texi2dvi

When compiling the following MWE with `texi2dvi -p`, the second `\index{}` command
fails with the error message `ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string`
(seems like this is because of `xindy` although `imakeidx` has default `makeindex`). The
resulting PDF looks fine (but it isn't; see 'Background' below), but the `.ind` file is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{makeindexstyle.ist}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\sffamily\\bfseries{"
heading_suffix "}}\\nopagebreak\n\\nopagebreak"
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc, options=-s makeindexstyle.ist]

\begin{document}
\index{$\bm{X}$}% works well
\begin{align}
  \Pi(\bm{u})=\prod_{j=1}^du_j,\quad\bm{u}\in[0,1]^d,\label{def:pi}\index{$\Pi$}% produces "ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string" and "/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi: texindy failed"
\end{align}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Background: I have a large document with tons of `\index{}` commands which
used to work well when compiling with `texi2dvi -p` (even when having
complicated symbols as arguments) .  Due to another issue, I had to upgrade
to a newer version of `texi2dvi` from `https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/texinfo/` and I then
realized (see also my inline comment above) that `texindy` is used instead
of `makeindex` (although `makeindex` is the default for `imakeidx`). Apart from
the error, the whole index looks fine, shows the right page numbers, but the
hyperlinks (not included in the above MWE) lead to wrong pages. I am (also) wondering whether this has to
do with the incompatibility of `xindy` (which I don't understand why it is
used instead of 'makeindex') and `hyperref` in general, or the above error
in particular.

This is on macOS 10.14.1 with pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018). The compilation with `texi2dvi -p` is done after setting `PDFLATEX=pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -file-line-error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string`

This error message occurs when Xindy encounters an empty sort value. In the case of `\index{$\Pi$}` the actual value is `$\Pi$`. Since there's no sort value specified in this case, the sort value is obtained from the actual value, but all commands and instances of `$`, `{` and `}` are stripped. This means that `$\Pi$` ends up as an empty string and Xindy has no way of knowing how to sort it, which is why it generates an error and fails.

The solution is to provide Xindy with a sort value that it will accept. For example, `\index{P@$\Pi$}` which sets the sort value to `P`.

In the case of `\index{$\bm{X}$}`, the actual value is `$\bm{X}$` so the sort value ends up as `X`, which is valid and so doesn't cause a problem.

In the case of `makeindex`, the sort value (if not provided) is also taken from the actual value, but no adjustment is made, so with `\index{$\Pi$}` the sort value is `$\Pi$`, which from `makeindex`'s point of view is a string consisting of five characters: `$` `\` `P` `i` and `$`. No error occurs in this case and the term ends up in the symbols group since it starts with a non-letter (`$`).

There may however be another source of conflict in your document build process. The `imakeidx` package automatically runs `makeindex` using the shell escape and your provided `makeindexstyle.ist` style file, but the subsequent `texindy` call made after the LaTeX call is overwriting the `.ind` file that was created by `makeindex` and doesn't recognise the style file. Once the above problem is fixed and the `texindy` call no longer fails, then the `.ind` file will then be overwritten by the next LaTeX call which runs `makeindex`. So you end up with a redundant `texindy` call and the final index file is the one created by `makeindex` through the shell escape.

You can prevent `imakeidx` from automatically running `makeindex` with the `noautomatic` option. In which case your `makeindexstyle.ist` file becomes redundant and instead you need to define `\lettergroup`. For example:

```
\newcommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
    \par\textbf{\sffamily#1}\par
    \nopagebreak
}
```

The change in `texi2dvi` seems to stem from replacing the line:

```
run $makeindex $index_files
```

with

```
  if $TEXINDY --version >&6 2>&1; then
    run $TEXINDY $index_files
  else
    run $MAKEINDEX $index_files
  fi
```

which enforces the use of `texindy` if it's been installed. There doesn't seem to be any way of changing this as far as I can tell.